# Want to perform different task on mousedown and click event

Tags: javascript, jquery

In `JavaScript` `mousedown` event followed by `mouseup` and `click`. so in click event three of this event execute. But in my task, i want to do the different task for `mousedown` and `click`.
if anyone **press and hold mouse** for a while then a list will show and click event will not execute.
when just click then the task for the click will execute.
It is as like as chrome back arrow functionality.
anyone to help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: mousedown + mouseup  = One complete click. So If mousedown event is triggered then automatically mouseup  event will happen.

Comment: yes i know, i want different task for mousedown for a time duration and click.

Comment: do you have an event handler added for `click` event?

Comment: no i dont have, i have some css change and class add remove for click

Comment: on `mousedown` `store time`, on `click` `click handler` on `mouseup` `compare time if > "hold duration" mouseup handler`

Comment: @ShahadatAtom, check [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40464997/2545680) then

Comment: @freedomn-m Will you please give an example.

Comment: @ShahadatAtom, an example of what? I've added working example to my answer. Just clicking alerts `click`, long press alerts `long click`

Comment: TBH: This is not how a "normal" "long click" works - it took me a while to work out what you were trying to acheive.  The normal process would be that the list would show *while you are still holding down the mouse* (at least, that's how it works on mobiles) otherwise you could be holding it down for 10 seconds or more!!  So:  on `mousedown` `setTimeout to show long click` on `mouseup *and* mouseout` `clearTimeout`.  Then the list will show while still holding down the button and it will make more sense to the user.

Comment: @ShahadatAtom, did you try my solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For both event working in same selector:

```
var pressTimer, longClick;

function mouseUpCheck() {
  clearTimeout(pressTimer);
  window.removeEventListener('mouseup', mouseUpCheck);   
}

document.querySelector('.mySelector').addEventListener('mousedown', function(){
  window.addEventListener('mouseup', mouseUpCheck);
  pressTimer = window.setTimeout(function() {
  longClick = true; 
  //code for longclick
  },2000);
});

document.querySelector('.mySelector').addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  if (longClick) {
    longClick = false;
    event.stopPropagation();
    event.preventDefault();

    return;
  }

  // code for simple click
});
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do it like this:

```js
var pressTimer, longClick;

function mouseUpCheck() {
  clearTimeout(pressTimer);
  window.removeEventListener('mouseup', mouseUpCheck);   
}

document.querySelector('.link').addEventListener('mousedown', function(){
  window.addEventListener('mouseup', mouseUpCheck);
  pressTimer = window.setTimeout(function() { longClick = true; alert('long click'); },2000);
});

document.querySelector('.link').addEventListener('click', function() {
  if (longClick) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    event.preventDefault();
    longClick = false;
    return;
  }

  alert('click');
});
```

```html
<a class="link">click me</a>
```

Comment: This will have the same issue as mine initially did, forgot about mouseup event may not fire if you move the mouse away from the initial control.  To see this in your snippet,.. If you increase the timeout to say 2 seconds, mousedown on control, instantly move the mouse away from control, let go of mouse and wait.  You will get the `alert` even though you never held for 2 seconds.  Saying this, I think the setTimeout has the advantage that at least errors like this don't leak, my setInterval leaked in this instance..  Add  mouseup on the window object and this should be the accepted answer.

Comment: I tried this but when i click 1st it working, but when i click after long click its not working for click

Comment: @ShahadatAtom, do you want to have both events `long click` and `click`? Because you're writing _if anyone press and hold mouse for a while then a list will show and click event will not execute_ and I understood that you wanted only long click to occur when mouse is pressed and held

Comment: Yes both event, but not at a time. I solve it, your ans was helpful, Thanks a lot.

Comment: @ShahadatAtom, you're welcome. You can accept my answer or post yours

Answer (score 3):

Mousedown doens't generate multiple events for down, so here I've used a setInterval to keep checking if the mouse is still down.

Just done a quick mod, forgot that a mouseup on an element doesn't get triggered if you mouse out of the element.  So here I'm attaching the event to the window instead.

```js
var d = document.querySelector('div');
var dtime;
var i;


d.onmousedown = function () {
  window.addEventListener('mouseup', mouseUpCheck);
  dtime = new Date();
  i = setInterval(function () {
    if (dtime) {
      var t = new Date();
      if (t.getTime() - dtime.getTime() >= 2000) {
        dtime = null; //stop now..
        console.log('2 second mousedown');
      }
    }
  }, 50);
}
function mouseUpCheck() {
  dtime = null;
  window.removeEventListener('mouseup', mouseUpCheck);   
  clearInterval(i);
}
```

```html
<div>Click Hold for 2 seconds</div>
```